# Get App Store rankings by API or RSS generator

Tags: app-store

I want to track my app's ranking on the App Store and have found https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us

**It pretty much does what I need** except for the fact that it only distinguishes between "games" and "all" - there is no option to just say "apps" (excluding games).

Also, I cannot set categories e.g. "Finance" etc.

My workaround would be to get both lists, make a new list that filters all "games" list entries from the "all" list and then check for each app's category by scraping the iTunes website.

However, I don't think that this is the way to do it.

Is there another API to use or an undocumented part in the rss generator that allows for what I am looking for?

Comment: you don't need additional api.. every app json contains genres, which your program can filter further. e.g. to list entertainment apps use 6016 idhttps://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/id6016

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately I can't filter after 'grossing' there, it only shows free apps and I can't find a way to show more results - any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

there are some resources, and I'm not an expert in them, but for example you can find genre charts:

All RSS URLS for genreId = 6000

`https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=6000`

Example Chart URL for genreId=6000

`https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/charts?cc=us&g=6000&name=FreeApplications`